# How to reset the scroll position in a Kendo Dialog (jquery)

Tags: jquery, scroll, kendo-ui, modal-dialog

I am wanting to re-open a previously opened kendo dialog.  The dialog has scrolling content so when it re-opens I want to be at the top of the dialog again.  How?  Or will I need to destroy and re-create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's .scrollTop() - https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Call .scrollTop(0) on the scrollable element when the dialog is opened. You could use either the open or show event of the dialog (probably open in this case).

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog/events/open

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog/events/show

Comment: Thanks.  $(".k-dialog-content").scrollTop(0) worked.

Comment: I have the same requirement but I want to reset it when it is already closed. But unfortunately I get the value 0 when it is closed. But when I open it again it shows the last scrollTop value again.